# Why does case statement in Oracle doesn't work for string comparisons?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, case

I'm puzzled by this in Oracle

```
select case when 'hello' <> '' then 1 else 2 end from dual;
```

returns 2

```
select case when 'hello' <> 'hello' then 1 else 2 end from dual;
```

returns 2

however on `SQL*Server` this works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Empty string in Oracle acts as null - so your comparison `<> null` will be always false...
(edit proposed by [igr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377101/igr))